# How to execute Perl one liner inside Perl script

Tags: perl

I want to execute below one liner in Perl script, to match a line with the values of variables `owner` and `type` and delete it from the file:

```
perl -i -ne\"print unless /\b${owner}\b/ and /\b${type}\b/;\" /tmp/test
```

Content of `/tmp/test`:

```
node01    A    10.10.10.2
node02    A    10.20.30.1
```

This works perfectly fine when I execute in shell, but the same does not work in a Perl script.

I have tried to use backticks, `system` and `exec`. Nothing seems to work.

```
`perl -i -ne\"print unless /\b${owner}\b/ and /\b${type}\b/;\" /tmp/test`

system(q(perl -i -ne\"print unless /\b${owner}\b/ and /\b${type}\b/;\" /tmp/test));
```

Is it possible to execute Perl one liners inside a Perl script?

If so, what am I doing wrong here?

Note: I don't need solution to delete a line from a file with sed, grep, awk etc.

Comment: you should print out the command you are trying to execute, you should see the problem then: `print q(perl -i -ne\"print unless /\b${owner}\b/ and /\b${type}\b/;\" /tmp/test);`

Comment: Also take a look at [`q{}`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) in perldoc perlop.

Comment: Why run another perl when you're already in perl? Read `perlrun` to see what `-i` and `-n` do - they can be trivially replicated on your own. `-i` may look large, but you don't actually need most of it.

Comment: Honestly, I'd suggest "don't". It's confusing at best. Just expand it out - `perl -MO=Deparse` will do a certain amount of that for you and you'll get a faster and clearer script as a result. One liners are convenient, but they're not good programming style

Answer (score 5):

You wouldn't want to generate Perl code from the shell, so you'd use one of the following from the shell:

```
perl -i -ne'
   BEGIN { $owner = shift; $type = shift; }
   print unless /\b\Q$owner\E\b/ and /\b\Q$type\E\b/;
' "$owner" "$type" /tmp/test
```

or

```
ARG_OWNER="$owner" ARG_TYPE="$type" perl -i -ne'
   print unless /\b\Q$ENV{ARG_OWNER}\E\b/ and /\b\Q$ENV{ARG_TYPE}\E\b/;
' /tmp/test
```

The Perl equivalents are

```
system('perl',
   '-i',
   '-n',
   '-e' => '
      BEGIN { $owner = shift; $type = shift; }
      print unless /\b${owner}\b/ and /\b${type}\b/;
   ',
   $owner,
   $type,
   '/tmp/test',
);
```

and

```
local $ENV{ARG_OWNER} = $owner;
local $ENV{ARG_TYPE}  = $type;
system('perl',
   '-i',
   '-n',
   '-e' => 'print unless /\b\Q$ENV{ARG_OWNER}\E\b/ and /\b\Q$ENV{ARG_TYPE}\E\b/;',
   '/tmp/test',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling a one-liner, you could emulate the `-i` and `-n` flags.  `-n` just requires a while loop.  `-i` involves creating and writing to a temporary file and then renaming it to the input file.

To choose the temporary filename, you could use `/tmp/scriptname.$$` which appends the processId to a basename of your choice.  A more sophisticated solution could use [File::Temp](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Temp.html).

```
open(IN, "<$file") || die "Could not open file $file";
open(OUT, ">$out") || die "Could not create temporary file $out";
while(<IN>) {
    print OUT $_ unless /\b$owner\b/ and /\b$type\b/;    
}
close(IN);
close(OUT) || die "Could not close temporary file $out";
rename($out, $file) || die "Failed to overwrite $file";
```